# populate datatable from external JSON into Datatables - servser side processing

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, datatable, server-side

I am trying to load datatable from ajax response and then perform server-side processing.

this is the response I am receiving from server :

```
{"msg":null,"code":null,"status":null,"result":[{"aNumber":"3224193861","bNumber":"3215910681","cellID":"410-06-325-13123","dateTime":"2017-06-05 09:44:22.0","duration":778,"imei":"47350901163665","imsi":"33372328617146","operatorId":2,"mscId":"3","fileId":"2"},{"aNumber":"3224193861","bNumber":"3028540439","cellID":"410-01-737-38540","dateTime":"2017-04-26 18:53:23.0","duration":266,"imei":"31489802062929","imsi":"34116567506606","operatorId":3,"mscId":"5","fileId":"2"}],"draw":1,"limit":1000,"recordsFiltered":13419,"recordsTotal":13419}
```

and this my method to call Ajax,

```
var cdrReqParams = {};
cdrReqParams.draw = '1'; // need to change with the value from server in next server side ajax call
cdrReqParams.offset = 0; // need to change with the value from server in next server side ajax call
cdrReqParams.newRequest = '1';
cdrReqParams.totalRecords = '1'; // need to change with the value from server in next server side ajax call
cdrReqParams.lookInCol = 'aNumber';
cdrReqParams.lookInVal = anumber;
cdrReqParams.fromDate = startdate;
cdrReqParams.toDate = enddate;

var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(cdrReqParams);
console.log(jsonStr);
API.call("getBasicCallAnalysisData.json", 'POST', function(data) {
    basicData = data.result; // Response from server

}, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
}, jsonStr);
```

I am receiving server response in basicData, How can I load that json response into my datatable and then perform further server side processing and changing the required values (draw,offset,totalRecords) from server and perform another ajax call on click of page 2 ?

In case, this my API class:

```
var API = {
  call:function(url,type,successcallback,errorCallback,data){
    var data = (!!data) ? data : {};
    var callback = (!!callback) ? callback : function(){};
    $.ajax({
      contentType : "application/json",
      dataType: "json",
      //crossDomain: true,
      xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }, 
      url: url,
      data:data,
      type:type,
      success:successcallback,
      error:errorCallback
    });    
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you change the format of the returned json? To use a server-side data source, datatables expects the data in a [specific format](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side).

Comment: @markpsmith No, I can't because the same response will be used for other modules as well