# load datatable from custom response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I am working on datatables. I have posted 2 questions already related to my this question [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45819742/populate-datatable-from-external-json-into-datatables-servser-side-processing) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45823994/load-custom-response-in-datatable-using-server-side-processing).

AJAX CALL:

```
API.call("getBasicCallAnalysisData.json", 'POST', function(data) {
    basicData = data;

    createTable(basicData);
}, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
}, jsonStr);
```

this my json response from server:

```
{"msg":null,"code":null,"status":null,"result":[{"aNumber":"3224193861","bNumber":"3217284244","cellID":"410-01-604-30226","dateTime":"2017-06-24 23:08:09.0","duration":801,"imei":"27512671195807","imsi":"35788979525680","operatorId":1,"mscId":"2","fileId":"1"},{"aNumber":"3224193861","bNumber":"3217280585","cellID":"410-01-738-13433","dateTime":"2017-06-24 06:53:13.0","duration":198,"imei":"46341570864238","imsi":"33270572168878","operatorId":2,"mscId":"4","fileId":"2"}],"draw":1,"limit":1000,"recordsFiltered":13442,"recordsTotal":13442}
```

HTML TABLE :

```
<table id="table" class="display responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                <thead style="background-color:#303641;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>ANUMBER</th>
                                        <th>BNUMBER</th>
                                        <th>DATETIME</th>
                                        <th>DURATION</th>
                                        <th>IMEI</th>
                                        <th>IMSI</th>
                                        <th>CELLID</th>
                                        <th>OPRID</th>
                                        <th>MSC ID</th>
                                        <th>FILE ID</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                            </table>
```

and this is my function to load datatable BUT I am facing two errors:

```
function createTable(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $('#table').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "bFilter": false,
        "iDisplayLength": configData,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: ['colvis', 'print', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'],
        searching: false,
        language: {
            buttons: {
                colvis: 'Show/Hide Columns'
            }
        },
        "aaData": data


    });
}
```

The parameter `data` is response from server. Errors are :

> DataTables warning: table id=table - Requested unknown parameter
>   'aNumber' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error,
>   please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

and

> Invalid JSON Response.

any idea, how Can i populate datatable with JSON response ?

Comment: Your json seems valid, as per a test in [json Lint](https://jsonlint.com/)... You could check the type of the variable `data`... Maybe it is a string. Try: `console.log( typeof(data) );`. It should return `object`. For the other error... I think your HTML is needed to investigate.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette yes, `console.log( typeof(data) )`; returns `object`.  What next ? how to solve the issue ?

Comment: Do you have the table header `<thead>` with a row containing the columns title [like here](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html) in tab "HTML" ?

Comment: would you post your HTML and also which version of datatables you are using?

Comment: yes, I have posted my HTML table in my question

Comment: okay hold on... There is something else.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette By adding `<tbody></tbody>` now I face only one error _invalid json_

Comment: I think I found... Your are using the jQuery ajax (`$.ajax({...})`); to get the json, right ?

Comment: Yes, i have added my ajax call in my question as well

Answer (score 1):

There is two possibility to get your json into DataTables...

1. Use a [jQuery Ajax request](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
2. Use the [DataTables remote preocessing](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)

You use the first one.

There is two main problems to your code:

1. A superflous DataTables attribute.
2. A valid JSON, but not structured as DataTables expects it.

**#1**
The attribute `"serverSide": true,` basically says that you intend to use the "remote processing". So DataTables expects now an "ajax" attribute holding the PHP address to get the JSON. This missing attribute triggered the "invalid JSON" error.

*I hear you shouting loud about unclear error messages now!!! (lol)*

**#2**
DataTables expects the data structured as an array for the whole table...
This array has to hold arrays of "row" values. Example [here](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html).

That is not what you actually have.
So I made a function to "re-arrange" the data to satisfy DataTables expectations.

```
console.clear();

// A function to run trhough your json and restructure the data as an array of array.
function arrangeData(data){
  var datatableData = [];

  for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    var row = [
      data[i].aNumber,
      data[i].bNumber,
      data[i].cellID,
      data[i].dateTime,
      data[i].duration,
      data[i].imei,
      data[i].imsi,
      data[i].operatorId,
      data[i].mscId,
      data[i].fileId
    ];
    datatableData.push(row);
  }
  console.log(datatableData);

  return datatableData;
}

// Your original function not really changed...
function createTable(data) {

  $('#table').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    //"serverSide": true,     // This works with the "remote preocessing" ajax attribute.
    "bFilter": false,
    //"iDisplayLength": configData,   // I commented this one only because I did not have the "configData" variable.
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: ['colvis', 'print', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'],
    searching: false,
    language: {
      buttons: {
       colvis: 'Show/Hide Columns'
      }
    },
    "aaData": arrangeData(data)   // I'm calling the "arrange" function here.
  });
}

// This is to simulate the response you get form jQuery Ajax.
var dataset = {
  msg:null,
  code:null,
  status:null,
  result:[
    {
      "aNumber":"3224193861",
      "bNumber":"3217284244",
      "cellID":"410-01-604-30226",
      "dateTime":"2017-06-24 23:08:09.0",
      "duration":801,
      "imei":"27512671195807",
      "imsi":"35788979525680",
      "operatorId":1,
      "mscId":"2",
      "fileId":"1"
    },
    {
      "aNumber":"3224193861",
      "bNumber":"3217280585",
      "cellID":"410-01-738-13433",
      "dateTime":"2017-06-24 06:53:13.0",
      "duration":198,
      "imei":"46341570864238",
      "imsi":"33270572168878",
      "operatorId":2,
      "mscId":"4",
      "fileId":"2"
    }
  ],
  "draw":1,
  "limit":1000,
  "recordsFiltered":13442,
  "recordsTotal":13442
};

// Call the table draw function... Certainly in your ajax success callback.
createTable(dataset.result);
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/yoEOar?editors=1011)

Comment: so, you are saying that I cant implement server side processing(pagination) the way I am doing  ?

Comment: I didn't say that! I say there is two way of getting the data... And you used an attribute of the second way to do it, which caused the error about the json. --- Then, the structure of the data is important.

Comment: The solution you provided will not work with server side processing.

Comment: No... Because the JSON would get right in Datatables then. But if you can change how the server produces the json...  I did not read much about the "remote processing"... Maybe the data structure you actually have is close to requirements... Closer than now. I don't know.